# How to combine inline and horizontal form in bootstrap?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, inline

Anyone who can explain how this would be done in bootstrap?

[image: example]

First try was with 2 inline forms, but then the search button screws it up...
So i was thinking on a combination of an inline and a horizontal form.
Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess here is that you want to do this with as much bootstrap markup as possible and as little custom styling as possible, and in that case I would do it like so:

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="search" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Find</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="What are you searching for?"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">in</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">under</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <select class="form-control">
                                      <option>All categories</option>
                                      <option>Category 1</option>
                                      <option>Category 2</option>
                                      <option>Category 3</option>
                                      <option>Category 4</option>
                                      <option>Category 5</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <select class="form-control">
                                      <option>Within 20 miles of</option>
                                      <option>Within 30 miles of</option>
                                      <option>Within 40 miles of</option>
                                      <option>Within 50 miles of</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 cover-col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.panel-default {
    background-color: #e6ed9f;
}
.cover-col {
    height: 6em;
}
.cover-col .btn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
.cover-col .form-group {
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.cover-col .form-group > div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rbsthlm/0esp41y4/)